# Change font-smoothing in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to make font smoothing more MacOS like in Visual Studio 2010? I used to do that with GDI++ in VS 2008, but obviously that won't work in new Visual Studio. Is it possible to tweak WPF font-smoothing manually?

If anyone doesn't know about GDI++ you can [get it here](http://free.flop.jp/gdi++/upload.php). It is highly configurable, but the basic settings make fonts look like they do on MacOS, which is much better when you have white text on dark background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151027232043/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/visual-studio-2010-text-clarity-cleartype-and-aliased-fonts.aspx) on some options to try:

Turning off ClearType, Adjust font smoothing on OS level, change the environment font in VS.  Consolas font was an option they recommended in beta.

Here's a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20121007033616/http://windowsclient.net:80/wpf/white-papers/wpftextclarity.aspx) on improving WPF font clarity.

Comment: I use Andale Mono, doesn't help. The problem is exactly the opposite: ClearType is not bold enough no matter how you configure it.

Comment: How about increasing the font size?  Yes, a sad answer but a suggestion offered none-the-less.

Comment: My font-size is quite big. That's not the issue. The problem is that white text on black background has a lot of artifacts around letters with ClearType (on my screen anyway). Maybe it's better with better DPI.

Comment: Your link uses JPEG to demonstrate different types of font smoothing. Gah! Somebody shoot the author.

Comment: This is just a joke.... Wait for VS 2010 SP1.... *sigh*  Although, probably more truth than would like to think...

Comment: I apologize. Consolas IS much better. Although, not good enough for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that it improved it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Visual Studio extension called [Text Sharp](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7aafa2ea-8c54-4da8-922e-d26bf018514d) that lets you change the font smoothing settings.

Comment: From not bold, to even less bolder. I need the opposite, unfortunately.